# Creating PPM signal from 4 integrers

Tags: communication, rf, drone

I am currently building a MultiWii based drone, I have built the emisor-receptor that interface 4 analog signals(4 potentiometers to control the drone) and it works perfect, the receiver(arduino Nano, receives correctly the signal and parses it on 4 diferent integrers as expected (values between 1000 and 2000 because the MultiWii software expects that value range), but the problem is when I connect the receiver Nano to the MultiWii controller(Arduino UNO) the Arduino UNO receives incorrect values from the PPM signal(the four channels gets crazy unless the four potentiometers are turned full) so I think that the problem is the PPM generation process.

The problem is that I have taken code from internet to do that signal generation (because I don't know how to do it), and I don't know how to solve it.

Here I paste the NANO receiver to PPM code:

```cpp
#define channel_number 4 
#define sigPin 2         
#define PPM_FrLen 27000 
#define PPM_PulseLen 400 

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int ppm[channel_number];

struct Received_data {
  byte ch1;
  byte ch2;
  byte ch3;
  byte ch4;
};

Received_data received_data;

String input;
int throttle, th;
int aileron, ail;
int elevator, el;
int rudder, rud;

unsigned long lastRecvTime = 0;
int boundLow;
int boundHigh;
const char delimiter = ',';

SoftwareSerial hc12(9, 10);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  hc12.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(sigPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(sigPin, 0);

  cli();
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;

  OCR1A = 100;
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS11); 
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
  sei();

  reset_received_Data();
}

void reset_received_Data()
{
  received_data.ch1 = 0;     
  received_data.ch2 = 127;
  received_data.ch3 = 127;
  received_data.ch4 = 127;

  PPM_width_Values();
}

void PPM_width_Values()
{
  ppm[0] = map(received_data.ch1,   0, 255, 1000, 2000);
  ppm[1] = map(received_data.ch2,   0, 255, 1000, 2000);
  ppm[2] = map(received_data.ch3,   0, 255, 1000, 2000);
  ppm[3] = map(received_data.ch4,   0, 255, 1000, 2000);
}

void receive_the_data()
{
  if (hc12.available())
  {
    input = hc12.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (input.length() > 0)
    {
      //Serial.println(input);

      boundLow = input.indexOf(delimiter);
      ppm[0] = input.substring(0, boundLow).toInt();

      boundHigh = input.indexOf(delimiter, boundLow + 1);
      ppm[1] = input.substring(boundLow + 1, boundHigh).toInt();

      boundLow = input.indexOf(delimiter, boundHigh + 1);
      ppm[2] = input.substring(boundHigh + 1, boundLow).toInt();

      ppm[3] = input.substring(boundLow + 1).toInt();

      Serial.print(ppm[0]); Serial.print("   ");
      Serial.print(ppm[1]); Serial.print("   ");
      Serial.print(ppm[2]); Serial.print("   ");
      Serial.print(ppm[3]); Serial.print("\n");
      delay(10);
    }

  }
}


void loop()
{
  receive_the_data();
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

}

#define clockMultiplier 2

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
  static boolean state = true;

  TCNT1 = 0;

  if ( state ) {
    //end pulse
    PORTD = PORTD & ~B00000100;
    OCR1A = PPM_PulseLen * clockMultiplier;
    state = false;
  }
  else {
    //start pulse
    static byte cur_chan_numb;
    static unsigned int calc_rest;

    PORTD = PORTD | B00000100;
    state = true;

    if (cur_chan_numb >= channel_number) {
      cur_chan_numb = 0;
      calc_rest += PPM_PulseLen;
      OCR1A = (PPM_FrLen - calc_rest) * clockMultiplier;
      calc_rest = 0;
    }
    else {
      OCR1A = (ppm[cur_chan_numb] - PPM_PulseLen) * clockMultiplier;
      calc_rest += ppm[cur_chan_numb];
      cur_chan_numb++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, what the problem is. Please make clearer, from where to where you are sending data over which interface and what goes wrong with it. And why do you include the receiver code of the Nano (that you used for testing?), but not the sender code?

Comment: @chrisl I use an arduino nano as sender, an arduino nano as receiver and an arduino uno as flight controller, the send and receive process it correct because if I serial monitorize the data that nano receiver receives, it is correct. The problem is that that arduino nano after receive that data wirelessly, it must send the data over a wire in a PPM signal, and thats the problem, the PPM signal isn't sent correctly so I need help with the PPM signal generation.